# Mysterious Error Message When Opening Version Controlled .NET Solution

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

Whenever I open the solution containing projects that are version controlled using TFS, I get the following error message:

"The Team Foundation Server[Server URL] is currently unavailable. Thie solution will be opened offline."

Now, as the message says, the Server is not available, but the funny thing is, I have removed the server information from the TFS server list, therefore this message should not occur under the current circumstances.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have removed the server from Team Explorer/TFS settings, but have you removed the source control bindings?

Open the solution, go to File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control...

Highlight all rows within the grid, and choose Unbind.

Comment: Just tried that, but I get an error on the output pane saying, operation could not be done because memory could be corrupt.

Comment: Though this didn't solve my exact problem, but its close enough to what I intended to know.

Answer (score 0):

There'll still be a reference somewhere in the solution file, or quite possibly the project files.

Last time I had a weird reference, it turns out that the project file was of a specific type, and I had to change a GUID. (Yep, not clear).

Check your project GUID's.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Tools->Options->Source Control in Visual Studio, choose None as Current Source Control Plug-in, and then try again to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue had multitude reasons and it was finally resolved by reinstalling VS.